# Iterate through first level of json nodes

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON Array like this:

```
[    
    {
        "A": { stuff }
        "B": { stuff }
        "C": { stuff }
    },

    {
        "A": { stuff }
        "B": { stuff }
        "C": { stuff }
    },

    {
        "A": { stuff }
        "B": { stuff }
        "C": { stuff }
    },

    {
        "A": { stuff }
        "B": { stuff }
        "C": { stuff }
    },

    { 12.000 more of those nodes }
]
```

My goal is to iterate over each first level node, do some checks on them and if they conform to my criteria add the just observed node to a new json array. I have a couple criteria, so I want to filter my json structure basically.

This is what I have so far but somehow I'm not getting the jsonpath right

```
var path = @"C:\Users\....";
string json = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
json = r.ReadToEnd();
var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
var test = jsonArray.SelectTokens("$..*"); // This iterates through EVERYTHING, I only want the first level node though
foreach(var t in test){
    var x = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. You can just treat the `jsonArray` as an array and iterate through it. So JsonPath is not even needed. Thanks anyways!